# Create posts under certain page

Tags: posts, pages

I am a wordpress newbie and wonder whether this is possible; I used wordpress to create a website with different pages and subpages. Now I would like that new posts appear only under certain page, how can I do this? I tried but new posts always go under main page

Answer (score 1):

You can assign any page-- "Page", not blog post or CPT post/page-- to be the "blog posts" page by going to `wp-admin->Settings->Reading`, clicking the "A static page" radio box and selecting a static home page and blog page from the drop down menus.

[image]

If that isn't what you want, or if that doesn't work, then you will need to explain things a lot better.

Comment: I think he meant that he wants to display certain categories on own pages. e.g. "X" custom page displays only "uncategorized" news posts.

Comment: Maybe, but the question doesn't mention categories or anything else that might help decide.